# modifing in a pre-save hook not persisted

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a model that I modify using the pre-save hook in the schema. When saved, mongoose returns the modified data, __v is updated and everything looks dandy. But when I retrieve the model, my model isn't changed at all...

This is a slimmed down version of my sourcecode:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  version: {
    type: Number,
    required: false,
  },
  versions: {
    type: Object,
    required: false,
  },
  elements: {
    type: Array,
    required: false,
  },
})
  .pre('save', function(next) {
    version = Object
      .keys(this.versions)
      .map(function(key) { return parseInt(key); })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; })
      .reverse()[0] + 1;
    if (isNaN(version)) {
      version = 1;
    }

    this.versions[version] = {
      createdAt: new Date(),
      elements: this.elements.slice(),
    };
    this.elements = null;
  })
```

I do this because I need to keep all changes in a specific version, so that people can load in specific versions of the data, but the client should not know about these, and simply get a version-number and the correct elements.

Could you point me in the correct direction with my issue, or show me what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the 'next' function at the end of your callback when done:

```
next();
```